# Find values of a parameter p for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n}\ln^{p} \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was requested to find the values of the parameter p for which the following series converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n} \ln^{p} \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

I tried using [Cauchy's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) and the [Term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test), but reached a dead-end.
I also tried to use the ratio test with but it didn't seem to be helpful in this situation.

At this point we aren't allowed to use the integral test.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks. I edited my question.

Comment: Another formatting tip. If you use `\ln`, `\sin` etc. for common functions, your posts will look better and be easier to read.

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$?

Comment: @saulspatz we haven't learned that yet

Comment: Prove that $x-\frac{x^2}2<\ln(1+x)<x$ for $1>x>0$

Comment: @Ha995 Have you learned the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)?  This may be the simplest option here, using $b_n = \frac{1}{n^{p/2-1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the fact that
$$
x-\frac12x^2\le\log(1+x)\le x.
$$

If required it can be proved integrating the inequality
$$
1-x\le\frac1{1+x}\le1,
$$
obviously valid for $x\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{n} \ln^{p} (1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) 
&\overset1= \sqrt n \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt n} + O\left(\frac 1n \right)\right)^p \\
&\overset2= \sqrt n\frac{1}{(\sqrt n)^p}\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)\right) \\
&\overset3= \frac{1}{n^{p/2-1}} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^{(p-1)/2}}\right)
\end{align}$$
**Explanation:**

1. Using $\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}-...$ for $|x|<1$.
2. Factoring out $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ and using $(1+x)^p = 1 + O(x)$.
3. Expanding the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(1+x)\sim x;\;\text{ as }x\to 0$$
$$\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}};\;\text{ as }n\to\infty$$
$$\left(\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)^p\sim \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^p=\frac{1}{n^{p/2}}$$
The series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt n \left(\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)^p$$
converges if in the following fraction $$\sqrt n\frac{1}{n^{p/2}}=\frac{1}{n^{p/2-1/2}}$$
we have [p_series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#p-series_test) $$\frac{p}{2}-\frac{1}{2}>1\to p>3$$

Comment: Nice solution. Only one remark: the use of asymptotics can be problematic in some cases (in particular for not experts), here it works fine but in general I suggest an approch with the use of the remainder as in the solution by Vivid.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{\sqrt{n} \ln^{p} \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{p-1}}=\left(\frac{\ln \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\frac1{\sqrt{n}} }\right)^p \to 1$$

therefore by limit comparison test the given series converges if and only if the series $\sum \left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{p-1}$ converges that is for $$(p-1)/2>1 \iff p>3$$